# why the background image I add not show in render?

Tags: rendering

blender 2.81
I press shift+a to add image - background, and then go to render image, and the background image does not show up in the render result.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great addon exactly for this.

Go to *Preferences > Addons*  and search for *Images as Planes* addon.
Check it to enable it.

[image]

Then you can easily add a new image that will appear in your render.
*Add > Image > Images as Planes*

[image]

Note:
The way you described is for reference images only - thy're not supposed to be visible in a render.

Comment: This add-on works as the functionality that I had expected Blender to have. I wonder why this this feature does not exist natively and users had to search the web for a solution and install an add-on for this...

Comment: Hello :). It's an official extension shipped directly with Blender. To keep the UI clean, not all Blender features are enabled by default. But you're right, this one should be.